# Share google document with everyone under certain domain

Tags: google-docs

Google Docs allows to share the document with people and groups (title of the share dialog basically). But I'm presented with separate email addresses in autocomplete dropdown. I would like to share the document with everyone having their mail addresses ending with certain domain. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible if you are using G Suite and not regular Google Docs.  With G Suite Docs you can share the document across your entire G Suite hosted domain  Then you can share the document with all other users in that G Suite account using the 'Share' button in the upper-right.  This will only work for users who have an active active G Suite account on that G Suite hosted domain.  Also, it's good to click the settings gear icon and make sure the shared file is searchable by other users or they will only see it if you send them the link.